# program quitting before its meant to be finnished

Tags: java, while-loop

So im making a program for an assesment acts as a vending machine, asks you how many cans you would like to purchase and then calculates the values, asks for coins input (assuming the user is being sensible) and then tries to calculate the change given.

The problem i am running in to is that after the program reads in the values for the payment and calculates if it is enough with the following:

```
double coins[] = new double[]{2.00,1.00,0.50,0.20,0.10,0.05};

//A while loop so that it continues to go until the payment is equal or more than the cost
int count2 = 1;
while (payment <= totalCost){

  if (payment == totalCost){
    System.out.println("You have entered the exact amount of change! Thankyou.");
    break;
  }

  System.out.println("Please enter more coins: ");

  coinsIn[count2] = kbd.nextDouble();
  payment = payment + coinsIn[count2];

  count2++;
}
```

It just ends the program.

The problem is, that directly after that while loop i have this sample of code

```
double change = payment - totalCost;
int count3 = 0;
if ((change == coins[count3]) && (count3 <6)) {
  System.out.println("Your change is: ");
  System.out.println(change);
}
else{
  count3++;
}
```

That should run, but just doesn't.

For instance say the total cost is $4.50 and i enter in 2 x 2.00 and 1x 1.00 it should run through that if loop and find that in the coins[] there is a .50 value at coins[2], then print the message for the change and then quit.

This is the working example in the terminal:

```
   Please enter the amount of cans that you would like to purchase:
1
Please enter the amount of cans that you would like to purchase:
1
Please enter the amount of cans that you would like to purchase:
1
There are currently [297] cans remaining.
The total cost of your purchase is [$4.5].
Please enter your payment now:
2.00
Please enter more coins:
2.00
Please enter more coins:
1.00
```

It just ends right after that 1.00,

I do not understand what is going on here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. Everything compiles fine.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Run your code under debugger and you can see step-by-step progress and examine your variables.

Comment: it looks like one problem is that count3 doesn't increment properly. It would have to be in a while loop for the increment at the end to impact the earlier conditional.  Also, there is no declaration for an array called "coins" so it's hard to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: `change = totalCost - payment;` will be non- *positive* after the loop. Is that on purpose?

Comment: That was the simple mistake, thanks @fabian

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the initialization of count3 variable. Are you sure with the usage of count3??